# Command-line torrent client that supports multi-tracker extension the way uTorrent does it

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, bittorrent, client

I've tried many torrent clients available in the repositories, but haven't found any that support the `multi-tracker` extension ([`BEP-012`](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0012.html)) the way it is implemented in `uTorrent`.

That is, when there is a list of trackers, `uTorrent` uses peers from all of them, but linux clients use only from the first available tracker.

Is there any command-line clients (preferably native Linux) that support the `libtorrent` multi-tracker feature the way `uTorrent` does?

Comment: use utorrent for linux

Comment: even if multi tracker feature is not being used you still get the same speed usually so y the need for worry

Comment: No, that's not happening. If the first in the list is a tracker abroad, I'm having slow peers. If the second is local or nearby, I'd have fast peers, but the second tracker is never polled since the first is alive.

Comment: i never had that prob... but i think there is something like tracker preference

Comment: I had that problem many times, especially with long tracker lists. An I don't want to manually shuffle the list to search for good peers - I want that performed by the program.

Answer (score 1):

Deluge [supports multi-tracker torrents](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Faq#DoesDelugesupportmulti-trackertorrents), and it has a command-line client available in the Ubuntu repositories, [deluge-console](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/deluge-console) [image: Install deluge-console]

[image]

Comment: Does it support `multi-tracker` extension the way the `utorrent` does? That is, announcing to multiple trackers at a time?